# " Permission denied" when adding files to index with `git add`

Tags: git

I'm having trouble using git. I have 5000 pending changes in visual studio code that need to be committed. These are unstaged but I'm unable to stage them in order to commit. My .git folder exists in windows. All of my projects were on my desktop were in separate folders, but I just moved them all into one folder, named Projects, which lives on my Desktop. I have tried cd into this folder with no luck. When I type in `git add -A`, I get this

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
```

Apologies if I'm a bit unclear in what I'm looking for, I'm new to git and github. I would just like for the 5000 changes to be committed, and going forward for the files to be tracked. Thank you.

Image attached of the permission denied:

[image: Image attached of the permission denied]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have created your git repository in your user folder.
And this folder contains a lot of files that are in used by other processes.
So you won't be able to add them.

I think you have created your repository in the wrong place.

Comment: There's also a lot of files it wouldn't make any sense to add to git; things like cache and temporary files.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. This might be a silly question but can I grab the .git folder and move it elsewhere manually, or does it have to be done through the command line. Thank you

Comment: @toastTea I think that if it's a newly created repository, you'd better delete the `.git` folder and create a new repo (even if moving it should work)

Comment: thank you for all your help!  I figured it out. I messed around with git by following along to a tutorial ages ago, without actually knowing what Git was all about.Figured it out finally. Like you suggested, I deleted the git folder. Opened one of my projects, and typed git init which made the git folder, and I was then able to add and commit. Thank you, I finally got the hang of it, and now it all seems so simple haha